# Getting a distinct column value and all values with same name in other column

Tags: php

I have this table here

```
         name_relation       
[   id       name     age     head   ] 
[    1        X1       12       X    ] 
[    2        X2       22       X    ] 
[    3        X3       54       X    ] 
[    4        Y1       4        Y    ]
[    5        Y2       8        Y    ]
[    6        Y3       10       Y    ]
```

What i'm trying to get is the following

```
X: X1X2X3
Y: Y1Y2Y3
```

so i made this loop

```
$pre = null;
$ed = "";
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $head = $row['head'];

    if ($head != $pre) {
        echo $ed;
        echo "<div>";
        echo "$head:";
    }
    $ed = "</div>";
    $pre = $head;
    echo $name;
}
echo $ed;
echo "</div>";
```

at an empty page it worked perfectly, But when i put it with another code structures i discovered that the web browser was filling and fixing it automatically, But now i get an extra `</div>` at the end of the loop, How can i solve this loop to become

```
<div>
   X:X1X2X3
</div>
<div>
   Y:Y1Y2Y3
</div>
```

Comment: What database system do you use? It is easier to get the values already combined from the database.

Comment: @axiac MYSQL(MariaDB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible and not that difficult to achieve your desired result using PHP, the problem you have is easier solved in the database, using the appropriate query.

Try this one:

```
SELECT head, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '') AS all_names
FROM tbl
GROUP BY head
```

Replace `tbl` with your actual table name. You probably also want the results in a certain order. Add `ORDER BY head` for that.

The PHP code now becomes:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo("<div>{$row['head']}:{$row['all_names']}</div>");
}
```

That's all.

---

The PHP-only solution is to keep track of the current value of `head`, 
output the closing tag `</div>` when the value of `head` changes **but not before the first row**, output the opening tag `<div>` also when the value of `head` changes. Also, display the value of `head` only once, when it changes but display the value of `name` for every row. Don't forget to output a closing tag ` after the loop ends but only if iterated at least once (the query returned something).

This sounds difficult but in fact, is quite easy:

```
// The current value of $['head']
// We assume here NULL is not a valid value for it in the database
// If it happens that you have NULLs in the database in column "head"
// then make sure the query converts it to an empty string. For example:
//     SELECT IFNULL(head, '') AS head ...
$head = NULL;
// Process one row at a time
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($row['head'] !== $head) {
        // The value of 'head' just changed
        // Display '</div>' but not before the first row
        if ($head !== NULL) {
            // This is not the first row, there is a current value of 'head'
            echo("</div>\n");
        }
        // Display the opening tag '<div>' and new value of 'head', only once
        echo("<div>{$row['head']}: ");
        // Update the current value of 'head'
        $head = $row['head']
    }
    // Display 'name'; there is nothing special here
    echo($row['name']);
}

// After the loop, close the last <div> only if there is one ($head was changed)
if ($head !== NULL) {
    echo("</div>\n");
}
```

Instead of `NULL` in the code above you can use some "magic" string (it is called a "sentinel") that is not possible to appear in the `head` column in your database.

Comment: I added the query i used, Can you please apply this solution on it? Since i expected to solve the `loop` itself but your answer seems pretty easy and efficient to use, If possible can you explain it a little, Does `GROUP BY` here stops duplication?

Comment: The `JOIN` doesn't change much. Just consider it as part of the `FROM` clause. Assuming the original query on a single table is `SELECT head, name FROM tbl` I am sure you can easily figure out how to update the query I suggested in answer to match your actual query.

Comment: Can i get two values from the `GROUP_CONCAT()`? Like if i have another column like `age` and i want to `echo` the `name` with its `age` like this `X: X1(12)X2(22)X3(54)` `Y:Y1(4)Y2(8)Y3(10)` Can i achieve that with the first method?

Comment: As if i wanted to define both name and age to use them individually on their own `div`

Comment: I think you can get both `name` and `age` using something like `SELECT head, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCATENATE(name, '(', age, ')') SEPARATOR '') ...` but you better go back to the PHP solution. It provides you more flexibility on formatting the values.